# SQL: Group by Rollup with multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to be able to do a query that selects average values from different groups, but also the average values when only one of the groups are selected.

Below is the query + simplified table structure I am using atm.

```
create table income_region (year int,region varchar(40),income float)

insert into income_region (income,region,year) values (2000,'North America', 2000)
insert into income_region (income,region,year) values(2200,'Europe', 2000)
insert into income_region (income,region,year) values(2101,'North America', 2001)
insert into income_region (income,region,year) values(2001,'Europe', 2001)
insert into income_region (income,region,year) values(2400,'North America', 2000)

select avg(income) as avg_income ,region,year as year
from income_region group by region,year with rollup
```

Issue with the above query is that it only shows Null for region when year is also Null. Whereas what I would want are new rows where region is Null and year is 2000. And another one where region is Null and year is 2001.

So we get all types of variations as output (and not just for year). It should look something like this:

```
avg_income region        year

2200      Europe         2000   
2001      Europe         2001    
2100.5    Europe         Null
2200      North America  2000     
2101      North America  2001   
2167      North America  Null    
2140.4    Null           Null 
2200      Null           2000
2050.5    Null           2001
```

Comment: Given your sample data can you add your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately MySQL doesn't support either the Cube nor the grouping sets modifiers that would have made this an easy task.
Since rollup does form a hierarchy for the super aggregates, you will need to Union the results to get your full set of aggregates.

```
select avg(income) as avg_income ,region,year as year
from income_region group by region,year with rollup
Union all 
Select avg(income) as avg_income ,null as region,year as year
from income_region group by year
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you. Is this scaleable to more 2 columns. E.g. for 3-5 ?

Comment: Yes, but you will need to cone up with all required combinations of columns . You can also use rollup iwith your group  by columns in nreverse order for more than 2 columns, just make sure you are not calculating the same aggregates more than once.