# Group by Rollup with 3+ columns

Tags: mysql, sql

This post is a reference to the question I posted here:

[SQL: Group by Rollup with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884165/sql-group-by-rollup-with-multiple-columns/54884964#54884964)

I wasn't specific enough that the query needed to work for 3-5 columns (rather than just 2 in the simplified example), so I am trying again with an expanded example:

```
create table income_region (year int,region varchar(40),income float, sex varchar(10))

insert into income_region (income,region,year,sex) values (2000,'North America', 2000,'Male')
insert into income_region (income,region,year,sex) values(2200,'Europe', 2000,'Male')
insert into income_region (income,region,year,sex) values (2000,'North America', 2000,'Female')
insert into income_region (income,region,year,sex) values(2200,'Europe', 2000,'Female')
insert into income_region (income,region,year,sex) values(2101,'North America', 2001,'Male')
insert into income_region (income,region,year,sex) values(2001,'Europe', 2001,'Male')
insert into income_region (income,region,year,sex) values(2101,'North America', 2001,'Female')
insert into income_region (income,region,year,sex) values(2001,'Europe', 2001,'Female')
```

Below is one of the few queries I tried (based modifications from the answer I got in the linked post) which does not give the desired output:

```
select avg(income) as avg_income ,region,year as year,sex as sex
from income_region group by region,year,sex with rollup
Union all 
Select avg(income) as avg_income ,null as region,year as year, null as sex
from income_region group by year,sex
```

What the above query is lacking is null values for the "year" column. More specifically, these are the extra rows I want inserted as well.

```
Income    Region        Year       Sex

2300      Europe         Null      Female
2101      Europe         Null      Male
2100.5    North America  Null      Male
2400      North America  Null      Female
```

Comment: Just keep repeating the `union all`s for all the columns you need in the `group by`.  MySQL doesn't have built-in functionality for this.

Comment: I did try that, however I can't get the desired result. Could you write down the exact query in an answer?

Comment: There will be 32 different "rollup combinations", do you need all of those or just some ?

Comment: sql isn't designed to do data analysis you might want to consider investing in something that is - excel may be enough for your needs here.

Comment: Most likely need all of them.